# What is the best way to write a loop with no body

Tags: c++

I have a function `func` which returns `true`  or `false`. Until `func` returns `false`, I want to keep calling it. What is the least awkward way to do this?

```
do {
  // do nothing
} while (func());
```

or..

```
while (func());
```

or..

```
while (func())
  if (!func())
    break;
```

All of them look really awkward and unintuitive to me. Is there another solution to this altogether?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think option B is most commonly used, but you should make it more obvious that you have an empty loop body:

```
while (func())
  ; // do nothing
```

or

```
while (func())  { /* do nothing */ }
```

As a side note, this *looks* like some kind of busy waiting. If this is the case, it can and should usually be avoided by using OS-provided synchronization primitives.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. Glad I refreshed.

Comment: I prefer braces for the do-nothing, but otherwise agree 100%.

Comment: @Stiles: Yeah, that's also quite common. Added it to the answer.

Comment: Re. busy-waiting, don't assume that the OP is running this code on an OS that cares<g>  maybe its a microcontroller.  If the code is indeed running on a preemptive multitasker, then a sleep() loop is nearly as bad an idea.  OS developers spend ages designing, developing, testing and delivering plenty of synchronization mechanisms - these should be used if possible instead of lame polling loops.

Comment: @MartinJames: Then again, maybe this is not a busy wait at all.  It can be a function does lots of work and must be called an apriori unknown number of times until it returns `false`.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, this was targeted at x86. You're absolutely right, I fixed that suggestion. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @AndréCaron - true.  It's only the busy-waiting suggestion I have commented on.

Answer (score 10):

I used to write

```
while (func()) continue;
```

when I needed a full busy-wait loop (which was not very often). The keyword made it hard to miss the intent, and it gets compiled away. :)

Comment: +1.  Never though of this, I always use the lone semi-colon on the next line (see Niklas's answer) but I think I'll use this in the future.

Comment: This is the cleanest, most descriptive way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on Option B:

```
while (func())
{
    // no-op
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the third does something different - it will call `func` twice per iteration.

I'm guessing you want the second one, and it's not at all confusing to other people.

Comment: The first and second are equivalent.  The third does call it twice per loop, I suspect he meant `while (1) if (!func()) break;`

Comment: @Ben: The third is also equivalent, but it's not immediately obvious :)

Comment: @NiklasB.: Sort of.  It's unrolled by a factor of two, so the performance may be every-so-slightly different.