# Can somebody explain this weird loop for me?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I'm newer to c++ and today I looked at a game engine main render loop which looked like this:

```
for (register unsigned long long i = 0xaull; engine_tick(); kRuntimeStatistics::INSTANCE.FramesSinceStart++, ++ i);
```

Why did it have any body and when it is exiting? I thought for loops are for numbers only? And what does 0xaull mean behind the long i?

Comment: Presumably `engine_tick` returns a value that can be evaluated to `true` or `false`. Also this is pretty awful code

Comment: This is equivalent to `while (true) { if (!engine_tick()) break; kRuntimeStatistics::INSTANCE.FramesSinceStart++; }`. Presumably the `engine_tick()` function call is what's doing all the work, and it returns a `bool`-ish type that will stop the loop if it ever returns `false`y.

Comment: that makes sence! but whats that 0xaull

Comment: but the code was written by a professional and it is not wrong or is it? with awful you mean readability right?

Comment: `0xaull` is `0xa` (hex for 10) with the [literal suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant) `ull` (`unsigned long long`). The code is "right" in the sense that it's not wrong, but it's difficult to read and overcomplicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### General case

No the [`for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) is for any kind of iterative processing. Not only for numbers.

The statement

```
for (a;b;c) 
   d;
```

is (almost) the same as

```
{
    a;
    while (b) {
        d; 
        c; 
    }
}
```

The empty body means that the main benefit is already in the a,b and c.

#### Application to your statement

So  for your statement:

```
for (register unsigned long long i = 0xaull; engine_tick(); kRuntimeStatistics::INSTANCE.FramesSinceStart++, ++ i);
```

it's the same as

```
{
    register unsigned long long i = 0xaull;
    while (engine_tick()) {
        kRuntimeStatistics::INSTANCE.FramesSinceStart++; 
        ++ i;  
    }
}
```

#### Several remarks:

- the empty for body, with semicolon at the end of the line is extremely error prone (I spent a whole night debugging some code once, just to figure out that I didn't see the semicolumn, so that I was mislead by the indentation).  I'd therefore recommend to put the [semicolumn on the next line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10097230/3723423) with proper indentation, just to draw attention on the potential trap.
- the [`register`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) has no longer added value, since the compiler's optimizer do much better job than the manual selection of register variables. It is even deprecated now.
- the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) allows to combine two expression in one. I've translated this in a semi-column for the sake of clarity. Note that the `++i` could have been moved to the for body in the original code for the same reason.
- `0xaull` means that it is an hexadecimal [literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) (`0x`) of value `a` (A in hexadecimal is 10) of type `unsigned long long`.

Comment: I would recommend not using an empty statement for a `for()` loop. I would rather use the empty block `{ /* do nothing */ }`

Answer (score 2):

It will exit when engine_tick() returns false. A while statement doesn't need a body.
The ull on the end of 0xa just specifies that its an unsigned long long, while the 0x specifies that its in hex.